# Two styles in one echo

Tags: styles, echo

Hope someone could help me with this. I want to get output like this:

**Width (cm):** 46

I want **Width (cm):** to be bold and value (46) to be regular.

Here is echo:

```
echo "<p>". __( 'Width (cm): ', 'woocommerce' ) . $_wccf_pp_width ."</p>";
$_wccf_pp_id_width = get_post_meta($product_id, "__wccf_pp_width", true);
```

I know I can wrap whole echo in div and put some style to p tag but how to separate styles for field label (Width (cm):) and for value (46)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

echo "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>". __( 'Width (cm):</span><span> ', 'woocommerce' 
 ) . $_wccf_pp_width ."</span>";
$_wccf_pp_id_width = get_post_meta($product_id, "__wccf_pp_width", true); 

?>
```

I think this should work.

Comment: This works, thank you so much. I tried to put class into span instead of inline style but no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<p><b>". __( 'Width (cm): ', 'woocommerce' ) . "</b>" . $_wccf_pp_width ."</p>"`;

Use html bold tag (`<b></b>`)